# Download all SharePoint Lists on a Site as offline CSV files

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-list

Is there a way to download **all** SharePoint lists found on a SharePoint site as offline local CSVs, one CSV per list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using Power Automate, creating a flow to copy all Lists as CSVs inside a Document Library. It becomes easy afterwards to download all of these CSV files at once using SharePoint web portal.

The flow is designed thus:
[image]

Comment: I'd like to see the details about how you setup each step, like "Get items". I can't see how to get it to automatically pull the site address and list names into the Get Items step.

Comment: This will work on a specific SharePoint site and not on many sites.  In Site Address, be sure to select the same site as in previous steps, otherwise the flow will fail to execute or wrong lists will be exported. Under List Name, click the `V` symbol and choose Enter custom value to select dynamic content here.
Now choose DisplayName under Get lists banner. This will give us the names of the lists inside the site, on which we will execute.

As to the next action, namely Create CSV table: populate its From field with the dynamic content: `value` list of items element under Get items banner.